# Content Security Policy: Loading failed for the script

Tags: content-security-policy, rackspace, thunderbird-addon

I'm writing a Thunderbird Extension to add an email to a Rackspace email account spam blocklist.

Rackspace provides an API for adding emails to an accounts blocklist.

My Ajax GET Request is:

```
    $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(request)
        {
            console.log("beforeSend");
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Api-Signature", Signature);
            request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text");
            request.setRequestHeader("withCredentials", true);
            request.setRequestHeader('crossOrigin','anonymous'),            
            console.log("beforeSend Request %o: " , request);
            return true;
        },
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    method: 'GET',
    type: 'GET',
    url: Api_Obj.Url,
```

When I submit the Ajax GET request with the url:

https://api.emailsrvr.com/v1/customers/123456/domains/sandypondconsulting.com/spam/blocklist/EglogicsSoftech@outlook.com

(account number 123456 is placeholder for actual account number for security purposes)

I get:

Loading failed for the  with source “https://api.emailsrvr.com/v1/customers/123456/domains/sandypondconsulting.com/spam/blocklist/EglogicsSoftech@outlook.com?callback=jQuery36003174572175672028_1625074250859&_=1625074250860”.

I've set the manifest:

```
"content_security_policy" : "script-src 'self' https://api.emailsrvr.com; object-src 'self'",
```

The Ajax error function parameters have these values:

msg: error

error: error

When I click on the url in the Loading failed error I get:

```
<unauthorizedFault xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://api.emailsrvr.com/v0/Schemas" code="403">
<message>Authentication failed.</message>
<details>6/30/2021 1:34:21 PM</details>
</unauthorizedFault>
```

The unauthorized fault tells me that I've probably incorrectly generated the X-Api-Signature required by the Rackspace API.

So, looks like I have two problems:

1. Loading failed for script.

   2) UnauthorizedFault

I'm looking to solve the script loading problem first. And, then figure out the UnauthorizedFault 2nd.

Thanks, Ed